# How can I add some class to the p tag?

Tags: javascript, css

I want to add some class to the p tag. How can I do it?

```
const separatorsList = [
    { start: '<!-- Excerpt Start -->', end: '<!-- Excerpt End -->' },
    { start: '<p>', end: '</p>' }
  ];
```

Comment: Can you please add more of your code so we can help you?

Comment: You appear to have JSON; you'd be better off adding the class after adding the tag to the DOM. Also, you're expected to show an attempt.

Comment: Er...does `<p class="yourclass">` not work? Or do you not control this data? Where is it coming from and how exactly are you using it?

Comment: Don't ask "how to", try to do something, when the result does not come as expected, ask "why and how to fix" it.

Answer (score 0):

you can map your array and replace your start tag with a tag contains the class you want.

```js
const separatorsList = [{
    start: '<!-- Excerpt Start -->',
    end: '<!-- Excerpt End -->'
  },
  {
    start: '<p>',
    end: '</p>'
  }
];

const res = separatorsList.map(({
  start,
  end
}) => ({
  start: start.replace("<p>", "<p class='yourClass'>"),
  end
}))

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the full code and to give a little background. This is from `eleventy.js`. My aim is to style an excerpt in the blog. Right now, I have to go to each markdown file and style it. I was wondering is there a better way to do like adding a global one to the p tag.

Note: Sorry that my knowledge of javascript is very little.

```
function extractExcerpt(article) {
  if (!article.hasOwnProperty('templateContent')) {
    console.warn('Failed to extract excerpt: Document has no property "templateContent".');
    return null;
  }

  let excerpt = null;
  const content = article.templateContent;

  // The start and end separators to try and match to extract the excerpt
  const separatorsList = [
    { start: '<!-- Excerpt Start -->', end: '<!-- Excerpt End -->' },
    { start: '<p class="f5 pt0 mt1 pl3 black-70">', end: '</p>' }
  ];

  separatorsList.some(separators => {
    const startPosition = content.indexOf(separators.start);
    const endPosition = content.lastIndexOf(separators.end);

    if (startPosition !== -1 && endPosition !== -1) {
      excerpt = content.substring(startPosition + separators.start.length, endPosition).trim();
      return true; // Exit out of array loop on first match
    }
  });

  return excerpt;
}
```